# How to render component only when data is loaded via Angular Resolver

Tags: angular

Currently, the component shows up before the data has been loaded (via resolver)and i would change it.

I would have something like Guard. -> render only when data is stored.

I have 3 files: http.service, categories.service and resolver.

http.service has only http call
categories.service has method "dispatch" which has whole logic of getting data and subscribe into it.

My resolver:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ProductsCategoriesResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(private categoriesService: CategoriesService) {}
    resolve(): void {
        this.categoriesService.dispatch();
    }
}
```

categories service

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class CategoriesService implements OnDestroy {
    categories$: BehaviorSubject<CategoryModel[] | false> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
    categoryTitle$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    private subscriptions = new Subscription();
    constructor(private httpService: HttpService) {}
    dispatch(): void {
        this.subscriptions.add(
            this.httpService
                .getCategories(12)
                .pipe(tap((categores) => this.categories$.next(categores)))
                .subscribe(),
        );
    }
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

http service

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class HttpService {
    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    getCategories(limit: number): Observable<CategoryModel[]> {
        const params: HttpParams = new HttpParams().append('limit', limit.toString());

        return this.httpClient.get<ApiResponse<CategoryModel[]>>(`api/public/categories`, { params }).pipe(
            map((response) => response.data),
            map((categories) => {
                return categories.map((category) => {
                    category.image = {
                        url: `/assets/images/products/product_${Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1}.png`,
                    };
                    return category;
                });
            }),
        );
    }
}
```

route:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'page/1',
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    {
        path: 'page/:pageNumber',
        component: ProductsComponent,
        resolve: {
            products: ProductsCategoriesResolver,
        },
    },
```

Comment: What you want is exactly what resolve is for. You just haven’t implemented it correctly. Your resolve should return an observable that completes. If it does, the component will wait for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your setup actually is the only thing you need for the wanted behavior. Resolvers are meant to delay navigation until all defined resolvers for a route return a result (either synchronously or asynchronously). Your resolver returns nothing, so your navigation happens instantly, and getting data from the service only happens as a side-effect in the background.

You also seem to be mixing up a lot of good techniques were they aren't really meant to work together (like your explicit subscription management in the categories-service). It doesn't hurt you, but requests through the Angular HttpClientModule's `HttpClient` complete when the request finishes and your service is provided in the `root` injector of the application, meaning that OnDestroy will practically never get called (until the user closes the website).

You could alter your resolver like so:

```js
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class ProductsCategoriesResolver implements Resolve<Observable<CategoryModel[]>> {
    constructor(private categoriesService: CategoriesService) {}
    resolve(): Observable<CategoryModel[]> {
        this.categoriesService.dispatch();
        return this.categoriesService.categories$.pipe(
            filter(categories => !!categories),
            take(1)
        );
    }
}
```

This means that the resolver will only complete and navigation will only occur once the list of categories has been fetched at least once (and the value of the BehaviorSubject has changed from `false` to a list of `CategoryModel`).

**Do note** that this means that on the next request the navigation will happen instantly, because the BehaviorSubject still holds the value of the last request, so more work is necessary and you might want to consider changing the implementation further.

Take a look at the official documentation of [Resolve](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve), because there is a lot more to it (you can get access to the data in the route's snapshot, making the BehaviorSubject obsolete if you only use it for this purpose).